# Is there a formula for sum of all nCr for a given n, such that r varies from 0 to n in steps of 4.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I am trying to compute the number of possible ways, in which $r$ objects can be chosen from a bin containing $n$ distinct objects, such that $r$ is a multiple of $4$. ($r$ can be $0$).

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor}\binom{n}{4i}$$

When I am trying to compute this, it's taking a lot of time.

I have tried to find an equivalent expression by iteratively using the following identity, but I am not able to reduce it to a simpler form.

$$ \binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}\binom{n}{r}$$

Can someone help me find a simpler expression for the above expression? I am looking for an equivalent expression that's easy to compute.

Comment: This sequence, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 16, 36, 72, 136, 256, 496, 992, ... , is no. A038503 in Sloane's Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS).

Comment: Why did you just unaccept the accepted answer and switch to another answer, all answers being posted 7+ months ago?

Comment: Funny story ! I installed the StackOverflow mobile app yesterday. I didn't knew just a click on the tick mark changes the status of accepted answer with out requiring any further confirmation from the user.

Comment: Overall I dislike the idea of only one accepted answer, where there are multiple perspectives for same problem and people spend their valuable time and energy in writing such beautiful detailed explanatory answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. In fact, you can generalise by using steps of size $s$ so that the sum is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/s\rfloor}\binom{n}{sk}$$

Simply consider the $s$-roots of unity $\{e^{2(0)i\pi/s},e^{2i\pi/s},e^{4i\pi/s},\ldots,e^{2(s-1)i\pi/s}\}$ then input them into the binomial formula

$$(1+z)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}z^k$$

giving

$$(1+e^{2i(0)\pi/s})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{2k(0)i\pi/s}$$
$$(1+e^{2i\pi/s})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{2ki\pi/s}$$
$$(1+e^{4i\pi/s})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{4ki\pi/s}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(1+e^{2(s-1)i\pi/s})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{2k(s-1)i\pi/s}\, .$$

Add these up

$$\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}(1+e^{2ri\pi/s})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}e^{2kri\pi/s}\tag{1}$$

Notice the order of summation swap on the right.

Now, the inner sum

$$\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}e^{2kri\pi/s}$$

is a finite geometric series with ratio $e^{2ki\pi/s}$ and first term $1$.

- When $s$ divides $k$ this ratio is $1$ and the sum is simply $s$.
- when $s$ doesn't divide $k$ the sum is

$$\frac{1-e^{2ki\pi}}{1-e^{2ki\pi/s}}=\frac{0}{1-e^{2ki\pi/s}}=0\, .$$

We have, for $(1)$:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}(1+e^{2ri\pi/s})^n=s\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/s\rfloor}\binom{n}{sk}\, ,$$

or

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/s\rfloor}\binom{n}{sk}=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{r=0}^{s-1}(1+e^{2ri\pi/s})^n$$

In this case $s=4$:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}\binom{n}{4k}=\frac{1}{4}\left(2^n+(1+i)^n+(1-i)^n\right)\tag*{}$$

this may be simplified but I'll leave that as an exercise.

This method is called the "roots of unity filter" or the "discrete fourier transform method".

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic application of discrete Fourier transform and has already been explained on the site but here we go: for every complex number $z$, the binomial identity reads $$\sum_k{n\choose k}z^k=(1+z)^n$$ hence, if one can find a finite collection $Z$ of complex numbers such that $$\sum_{z\in Z}z^k=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}c&\text{if $4$ divides $k$}\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.\tag{$\ast$}$$ then one gets $$c\sum_k{n\choose4k}=\sum_{z\in Z}(1+z)^n$$ Now, it happens that the set of fourth unit roots $$Z=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$$ solves $(\ast)$ for $c=4$ hence $$4\sum_k{n\choose4k}=2^n+(1+i)^n+0^n+(1-i)^n$$ Finally, $$1\pm i=\sqrt2e^{\pm i\pi/4}$$ hence, for every positive integer $n$, $$\sum_k{n\choose4k}=2^{n-2}+2^{(n-2)/2}\cos(n\pi/4)$$ For $n=0$, the term $0^n$ is $1$ hence one finds again the correct value.